# How should I attach laminate foil dryer transition duct?

Tags: ventilation, dryer, exhaust-vent, ducts

I've got a laminate foil dryer duct coming up from the crawlspace.  I need to attach my dryer transition duct to the exhaust duct, but these really don't like to go inside one another since they're exactly the same size.

I managed to force on inside the other and secured them together with duck tape (If this is a bad idea, please let me know!).  Are there better ways of doing this other than getting into the crawlspace and installing a new exhaust vent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duct Tape is good for a lot of things, except duct work!  It will eventually dry up and pull away from the heat in the vent.

I would bend/dent one of the ends slightly so that it will fit easily inside of the other.  Then I'd secure it with proper HVAC foil tape, followed by a clamp around it.

**Foil Tape**

[image: Foil Tape]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/c0bbd875-88ed-48d7-b92a-993dd7d95717_4.jpg))</sub>

**Metal Gear Clamp**

[image: Gear Clamp]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/10263.MC4ZW_4.jpg))</sub>

Comment: +1, duct tape will also fail in high temperatures since the adhesive will become soft.